# How to run global npm binaries with Ansible

Tags: gulp, ansible

1. I've set my npm global install path with `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-packages`
2. I've updated my PATH to include this. In `~/.profile` I have `PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"`
3. I have installed gulp with `npm install -g gulp`, verifying that it exists in `~/.npm-packages/bin/gulp`
4. I have verified that it is in my PATH and executable by SSHing into my remote machine and typing `gulp`

I'm using the following Ansible task:

```
name: Run gulp
command: gulp
args:
  chdir: app/
```

but it always errors out with the following:

```
{"cmd": "gulp", "failed": true, "rc": 2}
msg: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Why am I able to run `gulp` from a SSH session but not via Ansible?

Comment: I'm wondering if it's a good idea to setup a whole dev environment in production just to minify some CSS/JS. Any argument pro/against?

Comment: I wanted my server to be able to just pull the git repo and then be able to completely take care of itself and be able to rebuild itself should something catastrophic happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was finally able to do this with the following.

```
- name: Run gulp
  command: ~/.npm-packages/bin/gulp
  args:
    chdir: app/
```